# Google Custom Search. Can we increase the number of search page ?

Tags: google-custom-search

I am creating a Google Search Page and the result is only limited to 10 pages.

Is there a possibility to increase the result pages ?

Answer (score 0):

From http://moz.com/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters:

> num=xx
>
> Controls the number of results shown. Must be a numeric value, and can be anything up to 100. >Doesn't work with fractions. I've tried.

However Google Instant Search is locked to 10 pages.  If you want to control the number of pages then disable it with noj=1

https://www.google.com/webhp?num=30&noj=1 
That link will lock results to 30 per page.

Comment: Custom search != google.com FYI though I think it can be configured somewhere in the customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);